Simplification of $(X_1 \times X_2) \setminus ((X_1 \setminus U) \times (X_2 \setminus V))$, $X_1, X_2$ infinite and $U \subset X_1, V \subset X_2$
I am trying to derive a simplification of this set equation. I am trying to work through it "intuitively," but I am stuck and am wondering of any set theory that can help me simplify this expression or "distribute" $(X_1 \times X_2)$ over the rest of the expression.
So far, I have this:
"The Cartesian product $(X_1 \setminus U) \times (X_2 \setminus V)$ gives all the pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ such that $x_1 \in X_1$ and $x_1 \not\in U$ and $x_2 \in X_2$ and $x_2 \not\in V$. Then, the complement of these pairs with respect to $X_1 \times X_2$ is precisely all pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ such that ..."
What's next? Any hints appreciated.

Using DeMorgans laws I get that originally $(X_1 \setminus U) \times (X_2 \setminus V)$ can be expressed as
$${(x_1, x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2 \ : \ (x_1 \in X_1 \land x_1 \not\in U) \land (x_2 \in X_2 \land x_2 \not\in V)}$$
then taking the complement becomes
$${(x_1, x_2) \in X_1 \times X_2 \ : \ (x_1 \not\in X_2 \lor x_1 \in U) \lor (x_2 \not\in X_2 \lor x_2 \in V))}.$$
Is this not just $x_1 \in U \lor x_2 \in V$? What?

... all ordered pairs  $(x_1, x_2)\in X_1 \times X_2$ such that $x_1\in U$ or $x_2\in V$. So, this complement is$$(U\times X_2)\cup(X_1\times V).$$

@AnneBauval Thank you!

Perhaps the visual in this Desmos demo may clear it up from an "intuitive" standpoint, wherein
$$\begin{align*}
X_1 &= [x_{\text{lower}}, x_{\text{upper}}] \\
U   &= [u_{\text{lower}}, u_{\text{upper}}] \\
X_2 &= [y_{\text{lower}}, y_{\text{upper}}] \\
V   &= [v_{\text{lower}}, v_{\text{upper}}] \\
\end{align*}$$
with $X_1 \supseteq U$ along the horizontal axis, and $X_2 \supseteq V$ along the vertical. Then:

The entirety of the box is $X_1 \times X_2$.
The blue segment along the horizontal is essentially $U$, and that vertically is essentially $V$. (Or, rather, their projections onto the corresponding axes are $U$ and $V$.)
Anything in red is deleted by the set subtraction. The top-left, for instance, is all points $(x_1,x_2)$ where $x_1$ is too small to be in $U$ and $x_2$ is too big to be in $V$. You can give a similar argument for all the other red segments, since for red points $(x_1,x_2)$ we must have $x_1 \not \in U$ and $x_2 \not \in V$ (but both within their respective $X_i$ of course).
Likewise, anything in blue is what is left. These points are those $(x_1,x_2)$ such that $x_1 \in U$ (and $x_2 \in X_2$) or $x_2 \in V$ (and $x_1 \in X_1$), or both in the case of the central chunk. More precisely, then $(x_1,x_2) \in (U \times X_2) \cup (X_1 \times V)$.

We see then that
$$(X_1 \times X_2) \setminus ((X_1 \setminus U) \times (X_2 \setminus V))
=(U \times X_2) \cup (X_1 \times V)$$


HINT
I would recommend you to notice that
\begin{align*}
(A\times B)\backslash(C\times D) & = \{(x,y) \mid ((x,y)\in A\times B)\wedge((x,y)\not\in(C\times D))\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid (x\in A)\wedge(y\in B)\wedge ((x\not\in C)\vee(y\not\in D))\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid ((x\in A)\wedge(y\in B)\wedge(x\not\in C))\vee((x\in A)\wedge(y\in B)\wedge(y\not\in D))\}\\\\
& = \{(x,y) \mid ((x\in A\cap C^{c})\wedge(y\in B))\vee((x\in A)\wedge(y\in B\cap D^{c}))\}\\\\
& = ((A\backslash C)\times B)\cup(A\times(B\backslash D))
\end{align*}
Based on such relation, can you proceed from here?
